# HIve/Impala Converting String into Lower case before using in hql

Tags: hive, impala

I need to convert the name of the table into lower before passing it for the query.
Irrespective of which case in pass the value for parameter $1 i need it to be converted into lower case before executing the below query.

**QUERY:**
show tables like '$1';

I have tried something like

**QUERY**
show tables like 'lower($1)';

But this doesn't work.

please help.

Your response would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> Impala identifiers are always case-insensitive. That is, tables named
>   t1 and T1 always refer to the same table, regardless of quote
>   characters. Internally, Impala always folds all specified table and
>   column names to lowercase. This is why the column headers in query
>   output are always displayed in lowercase.

[Impala Documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_identifiers.html)

All the below queries **will give same result** as internally impala converts to lowercase.

```
show tables like 'test*';
show tables like 'TeSt*';
show tables like 'TEST*';
```